# Suggested Edits review queue

Tags: bug

I am one of the top reviewers on all queues except Suggested Edits, I hardly ever see any. I am doing review queues every time I open a new browser tab (its my default new tab), yet I only have had 94 (At time of writing).

Is there something else limiting this, as people who have been doing review queues for about the same time have hundreds.

Or is it just plain luck?

Further in contrast, I get a lot of first posts, and an average amount of the other categories.

Possible bug??

Answer (score 1):

I do see there is a greater number of First Posts than other categories also for me, but I also see a few suggested edits every now and then.

My guess is that most users editing posts here has high enough reps to not need to be reviewed , the total number of review tasks is substantially lower in Suggested Edits than First Posts

There are 16 "First Posts" done today, only 5 "Suggested edit"

Comment: Take you for example, only been here a couple months more, and 658 in edits, I have 94, and I think we are as active as each other on the queues as the others are even. There are a few users the same, you will see them often as top reviewers for the day, but never suggested edits, yet they have the rep for it, easily.

Comment: Well I think I'm not the best example (as hyper active as I am on this site) ;)

Comment: I'm up there with ya on review queues, only have 30min a day for questions sadly. The point is, certain people seem to get more of one queue than others, I was wondering if there is any filtering that is causing this

Comment: Funny thing is that the "Late answers" is not very often shown for me, but as it seems, more often to you? In that queue stats it is the opposite situation from the "First Posts"! But that category is not the most active one though

Comment: Yeah I get loads of first posts, you see what I mean, it's like its weighted some how. I don't think the weighting is working properly.

Comment: Also top reviewers for today, doesn't seem to be working... most of the time it shows no one or incorrect data. (Timer job?)